# Date and time from strings with various formats

Tags: php, datetime

Clients are creating tickets for my team with tasks to be done at various times. The date and time is written in the description but the format can be different with every ticket, for example:

> Todo : thursday 26th of april at 19
>
> Todo : Wed 25/04/2018 between 14:00 and 14:30
>
> Todo : Monday, 25/04 between 11 and 11:30
>
> Todo : 30.03.2018 13h30 - 14h00

I've created a function that takes the string containing the date and time (after exploding on colon) and tries to convert it to a standard format which can be used in a `datetime-local` field (don't care about seconds).

```
public static function getDatetime ( string $datetime )
{
    $formats[] = "dS * F * G?i+";
    $formats[] = "* dS * F * G?i+";
    $formats[] = "D d#m#Y * G#i+";
    $formats[] = "d M Y * G:i+";
    $formats[] = "* d F Y G?i+";
    $formats[] = "* d F Y * G?i+";
    $formats[] = "* j F * g#i A+";
    $formats[] = "* j F * h A+";
    $formats[] = "*# d F * g#i a+";
    $formats[] = "*# M d Y * G?i+";
    $formats[] = "*# F d * g a+";
    $formats[] = "* d F * G\hi+";
    $formats[] = "* d#m * G:i+";
    $formats[] = "d#m#Y G\hi+";
    $formats[] = "d#m#Y * G?i+";
    $formats[] = "* d#m#Y G\Hi+";
    $formats[] = "* d#m#Y * G\hi+";
    $formats[] = "d#m#Y * G\h+";
    $formats[] = "* d#m#Y * G\h+";
    $formats[] = "* dS * F, * G\h+";
    $formats[] = "* dS F * G\h+";
    $formats[] = "* d * M Y * G?i+";
    $formats[] = "dS * F * G+";
    $formats[] = "* dS * F * G+";
    $formats[] = "* dS F Y * G?i+";
    $formats[] = "* d#m#Y * G?i+";
    $formats[] = "* d#m#Y * G+";
    $formats[] = "*# dS M Y * G?i+";
    $formats[] = "*# dS M Y * G+";
    $formats[] = "d S * M * G+";

    foreach ( $formats as $format )
    {
        if ( DateTime::createFromFormat ( $format, $datetime ) !== false )
        {
            return DateTime::createFromFormat ( $format, $datetime )->format ( 'Y-m-d\TH:i' );
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

As you can see, I've created an array of about 20 formats which I'm looping through and I'm returning the formatted date as soon as the string matches a format. For this to work, I have to add the more specific formats before the more generic ones in the array.

This function works for about 80-90% of the cases I've encountered so far, excluding cases with typos or strings that are not even humanly readable.

The problem is, clients may randomly decide to, say, add a comma to separate the day name and date or invert the day number and month, in which case I have to create a new format.

A simple example:

```
$datetime = "Monday, 08 January at 8:00 am";
$formats[] = "*# d F * g#i a+";

$datetime = "Thursday, April 18 at 7:30 pm";
$formats[] = "*# F d * g#i a+";
```

Before I created this function, I tried to use `preg_replace` and `str_replace` to only keep what I needed from the string and then pass it to `strtotime` but that was definitely worse!

My question is, is there a better way of doing this? If not, could I at least do something simple to avoid having many formats (like the first 2) for strings that are very similar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

well, to avoid having too many formats then you need to limit the way your client to provide those information (e.g : for web app, rather than using textbox where user can put a free text with any format, use calendar control that return specific format only), this can avoid typo and invalid date (like 30 Feb for example).

otherwise, as you said, the client can just keep adding new format :)

Comment: Some browsers support a `date` input type: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date

Comment: That would of course be the perfect solution but unfortunately I have no control over it...